# Dynamically load random url from file into iframe

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, this is supposed to be running offline as a web page in my browser and should work without additional installs like php.

I have an iframe which content should be randomly loaded.
I have:

- /index.html (the page with the Iframe)
- /files.txt (a file with a
  list of relative urls)

and tons of .html files (also in subfolders). 
For each of these files exists an entry in files.txt with it's exact relative path.

If I wouldn't have so many files, I would just make an hardcoded javascript array with the relative urls and take a random entry from that array as source for the iframe.
But I'm talking about >6000 files.
So how can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just generate JavaScript code by parsing the contents of `files.txt`? `grep`/`sed`/`awk`? Not feasible if `files.txt` changes often though...

Comment: nice idea, I'm kind of a noob but I'll manage to do that with google for sure. 
My only concern is, that hardcoding an array with 6500 entries might slow down the loading time. 
Is that concern obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to load file list via AJAX, split it by `\n` and set random line as an `src` for iframe:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'files.txt',
  success: function(text) {
    var fileList = text.split('\n');
    var randomIndex = randomInt(0, fileList.length - 1);    

    $('iframe').attr('src', fileList[randomIndex]);
  }
});

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to use jQuery and AJAX first, then I'll try this.
Thanks

Comment: if I just paste it in the <script src=jQuery> tag and then beneath the </script> tag I put my iframe, it still doesn't work.
I'm sry but it seems like I do not know enough jQuery to implement this.
May you help me one more time?

Comment: Works online, but somehow not offline... :( 
(meaning when it's opened with "file:///home/stephen/index.html"
I need it offline :'-(

Comment: This might be caused by browser security settings. For example Chrome has special command line switch `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: even when starting chromium with that I get a:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/stephen/project/files.txt. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."
I do not want to eat your time, you helped me already enough. I can surely figure this out on my own.

Thanks much for your help <3 <3

Comment: No problem :) Also you can setup local webserver and host your start page at http://localhost/startpage.html This will work in any browser ;)